# move UIView within a form

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

So in my `UIViewController`, I have 2 more views.

If user picks one option on the previous `UIViewController`, this view loads with both subviews.  And If the user picks the other option, it only loads with the 2nd one.

I want to be able to move the 2nd view (bottom view) to the top if the top one is hidden.
But when I try to change the `Layer.Frame.Y` value of the view, it doesn't actually move the view.  But I can see the value changing by using breakpoints.

Here is what I did.

I have declared this at the class level.

```
public float dateAndTimeViewYWithoutOtherTypes = 38f;
public float dateAndTimeViewYWithOtherTypes = 81f;
```

In my ViewDidLoad,

```
if (this.label.Text == "Other") {
    this.view1.Hidden = false;
    this.view2.Layer.Frame = new RectangleF (this.view2.Layer.Frame.X, dateAndTimeViewYWithOtherTypes, this.view2.Layer.Frame.Width, this.view2.Layer.Frame.Height);
} else {
    this.view1.Hidden = true;
    this.view2.Layer.Frame = new RectangleF (this.view2.Layer.Frame.X, dateAndTimeViewYWithoutOtherTypes, this.view2.Layer.Frame.Width, this.view2.Layer.Frame.Height);
}
```

Can anyone please explain me what I am missing or doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

`this.txtView.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation (0, -88).`

For some reason, I have to double the `X` and `Y` number but it works.   So only need to move it up 44px but I had to do 88px but it seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code to viewWillAppear - frame geometry has not been set in viewDidLoad.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply Steve.  But I moved the code to viewWillAppear and it made no difference. The Y location is not changing.

Comment: Sorry @user3866010, moving code that manipulates frame from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear usually fixes the issue in Objective-C.  I assumed the same would be true using monotouch/xamarin.

Comment: well thanks for the info. I'm sure it will be useful at some point.  I will keep trying this.  The confusing part is that everything's being called, value is change, 1st view is hidden but no position change. But I'm sure I'm missing something very little somewhere.